# Is it a good practice to use jQuery object to load scripts onto page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am writing a website, and I've come up with quite a few scripts taking up a lot of space and ruining the aesthetics of my code. I came up with the idea of creating one script that fills a div below it with scripts, but that sounds like it could present some sort of problem. Is this an okay thing to do, or is this bad practice?

Comment: Sounds like a nightmare to me.

Comment: I'd just have an array of the URIs for the scripts and inject them into a div at the bottom of the page.

Comment: How about bundle all scripts into one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a formal convention such as require.js. For example, to load jquery-ui:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    paths: {
        // the left side is the module ID,
        // the right side is the path to
        // the jQuery UI file, relative to baseUrl.
        // Also, the path should NOT include
        // the '.js' file extension. This example
        // is using jQuery UI located at
        // js/lib/jquery-ui, relative to
        // the HTML page.
        jquery-ui: 'jquery-ui',
        jquery-ui-autocomplete: 'jquery-ui-autocomplete'
    }
});
```

and later on using the autocomplete plugin:

```
require([ "jquery-ui-autocomplete" ], function( autocomplete ) {
    autocomplete({ source: [ "One", "Two", "Three" ] }, "<input>" )
        .element
        .appendTo( "body" );
});
```

**References**

- [Using jQuery UI with AMD | jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/environments/amd/)
- [umd.js templates: jqueryPlugin.js](https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/templates/jqueryPlugin.js)
- [A Simple Async JavaScript Loader | Code Engineered](https://codeengineered.com/blog/simple-async-javascript-loader/)